# Como evitar conflito de dados entre duas requisições PUT no HTTP?

Tags: rest, http

**Quais técnicas podemos utilizar para evitar a colisão entre dados de duas requisições PUT para que as alterações da segunda requisição não sobrescrevam as da primeira?**

Imaginemos a situação:

- Há um produto cadastrado em um sistema de loja virtual de nome "Produto Bem Bacana", sem descrição e preço unitário R$ 10,00.

O JSON que representaria o recurso é apresentado abaixo, acessado via `/produto/1`.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",
  "description": "",
  "price": 10.00
}
```

Temos dois usuários ativos no sistema: Albert e Bohr; ambos acessam o recurso. Ficando, então:

```
[Banco de dados]                       [Albert]                              [Borh]

{                                      {                                     {
  "id": 1,                               "id": 1,                              "id": 1,
  "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",          "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",         "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",
  "description": "",                     "description": "",                    "description": "",
  "price": 10.00                         "price": 10.00                        "price": 10.00
}                                      }                                     }
```

Neste momento, Albert percebe que o produto está sem descrição e resolve adicioná-la.

```
[Banco de dados]                       [Albert]                              [Borh]

{                                      {                                     {
  "id": 1,                               "id": 1,                              "id": 1,
  "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",          "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",         "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",
  "description": "",                     "description": "É bacana mesmo",      "description": "",
  "price": 10.00                         "price": 10.00                        "price": 10.00
}                                      }                                     }
```

Albert, então, faz sua submissão ao banco de dados, atualizando o recurso:

```
[Banco de dados]                       [Albert]                              [Borh]

{                                      {                                     {
  "id": 1,                               "id": 1,                              "id": 1,
  "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",          "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",         "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",
  "description": "É bacana mesmo",       "description": "É bacana mesmo",      "description": "",
  "price": 10.00                         "price": 10.00                        "price": 10.00
}                                      }                                     }
```

Borh percebe que o preço do produto está errado. Ao invés de R$ 10,00, o produto deveria valor R$ 15,00. Desta forma, ele corrige o produto:

```
[Banco de dados]                       [Albert]                              [Borh]

{                                      {                                     {
  "id": 1,                               "id": 1,                              "id": 1,
  "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",          "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",         "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",
  "description": "É bacana mesmo",       "description": "É bacana mesmo",      "description": "",
  "price": 10.00                         "price": 10.00                        "price": 15.00
}                                      }                                     }
```

Borh, então, submete sua alteração para atualizar no banco:

```
[Banco de dados]                       [Albert]                              [Borh]

{                                      {                                     {
  "id": 1,                               "id": 1,                              "id": 1,
  "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",          "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",         "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",
  "description": "",                     "description": "É bacana mesmo",      "description": "",
  "price": 15.00                         "price": 10.00                        "price": 15.00
}                                      }                                     }
```

E acontece que as informações de Bohr estava desatualizadas depois que Albert fez suas alterações. No momento que Bohr submete as suas, a descrição que Albert havia adicionado se perde.

Então, quais técnicas podem ser aplicadas para que seja evitado esta colisão de dados? Como poderia ser feito para identificar, no momento da submissão de Bohr, que o recurso fora atualizado e que suas informações estão desatualizadas, impedindo suas alterações sobrescrevam as de Albert?

Citei o método PUT pelo fato de, geralmente, todas as informações do recurso serem enviadas através da requisição, não apenas campos alterados, como seria no PATCH - que sofreria do mesmo mal se Albert e Bohr alterassem o mesmo campo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode adotar o conceito de **Lock Otimista** para evitar que uma request atualize um recurso usando as informações antigas dele como referência.

Na [especificação HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) existem 2 cabeçalhos (*Headers*) HTTP que podem ser usados em conjunto para isto: o **[ETag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3)** e o **[If-Match](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.1)**.

## ETag

O conteúdo do `ETag` (*Entity Tag*) é uma representação única do estado atual do recurso. Esta informação pode ser desde um *hash* (criado usando MD5, SHA-1, etc) das informações do recurso ou mesmo algum `UUID` salvo com o recurso, que é alterado a cada atualização do mesmo.

A sua utilização funciona da seguinte maneira: toda vez que você solicita (`GET`) o recurso, você também retorna no *header* do response a informação de `ETag`.

Digamos que a representação atual do recurso seja o valor `b0c396189`:

```
GET /api/produtos/1

Response:
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",
  "description": "",
  "price": 10.00
}

Response Headers:
content-type: application/json
... demais cabeçalhos de response
ETag: b0c396189
```

Feito isto, o cliente deve guardar esta informação do `ETag` para enviar ela no `PUT`.

## If-Match

Ao alterar o recurso via `PUT`, você enviará a mesma informação que veio no `Etag` usando um outro cabeçalho, o `If-Match`:

```
PUT /api/produtos/1
Request:
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Produto Bem Bacana",
  "description": "Descrição",
  "price": 10.00
}

Request Headers
content-type: application/json
... demais cabeçalhos de request
If-Match: b0c396189
```

Feito isto, o servidor irá receber esta informação e comparar se o valor atual do recurso (`b0c396189`) no servidor é o mesmo que veio no cabeçalho `If-Match`. Se os valores forem os mesmos, significa que o recurso obtido no `GET` pelo cliente continua sendo o mesmo do servidor e que, assim, a atualização pode ser realizada.

Após a atualização do recurso produto, o valor `b0c396189` não mais representará o recurso. Como disse no início, este valor é uma representação única do recurso, então a cada atualização do mesmo este valor **deve** mudar.

Digamos que o novo valor seja `096849fba`.

Agora vamos ao exemplo de que, ao mesmo tempo, alguém consultou o mesmo produto. Esta pessoa ainda terá o valor antigo de `Etag` com ele, o `b0c396189`. Se este tentar fazer uma atualização do produto, enviando este valor `b0c396189` no cabeçalho `If-Match` do request, o servidor irá comparar este valor com o valor atual de `096849fba` e detectará a diferença. Neste momento, o servidor recusará a atualização, podendo retornar um erro `412 Precondition Failed`.

Comment: Tem algum link para documentação disso? Algo oficial ou não?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, tem sim, da RFC. Melhor que isto, não tem hehehe. Vou adicionar os links.