# Para uma busca sem resultados, a resposta HTTP deve ser 404, 204 ou 200 com o corpo vazio?

Tags: http, http-status, http-status-404

Quando buscamos algum recurso no servidor com algum tipo de filtro, por exemplo, uma busca de usuários, é retornado uma lista com os dados (em JSON, XML ou até já formatado em HTML)

Porém algumas pesquisas podem resultar em nenhum dado, então uma requisição para `/users/name/guilherme`, sendo que existe essa rota, porém não existe nenhum usuário com o nome guilherme, o mais semânticamente correto é retornar o código 404 ou um array vazio (`[]`)?

O mesmo se aplica quando buscamos algo específico, como buscar o usuário (singular) de id N (`/users/7`)? No caso em vez de retornar um `[]` retornaria `null`

**Pergunta para recompensa:**

O status 204 No Content, segundo a [rfc 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5):

> O código de status 204 (Sem conteúdo) indica que o servidor resolveu com sucesso o pedido e que não há conteúdo para enviar no corpo da resposta

Isso pode ser interpretado como uma consulta que não retorna nenhum registro. Mas também como uma requisição que retorna um 204 sempre deverá retornar esse mesmo status, independentemente se houve alterações nos dados, se houver uma mudança no retorno, deve-se entender como uma mudança na API (a não ser que retorne algum status de erro)

Então qual cenário seria correto o uso? Ambos?

Comment: Retorne o *status 200* com um array vazio. O *status 404* deve ser utilizado para quando um recurso não for encontrado (por exemplo, a URL não existir). No teu exemplo, a URL existe, o que não existe são os dados.

Comment: Segundo a *W3*, no protocolo de definições de *status code*: `404 = O servidor encontrou nada que corresponda ao URI de solicitação.`

Comment: Eu sempre utilizo o 404 NotFound, e muitos projetos no github também utilizam o 404, gosto de seguir esse padrão porque é auto explicativo e amplamente utilizado. Segue um artigo bacana sobre o assunto:
https://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow

Comment: Isso é totalmente relativo e baseado na interpretação e definição de quem constrói a API, por exemplo, eu acredito que 404 não deva ser utilizado, visto que serve para dizer se você conseguiu realizar a chamada ao serviço, e que ele não está fora do ar. Eu utilizaria o 204 (No-Content) visto que o servidor está no ar, realizou a pesquisa, e não encontrou nenhum conteúdo.

Comment: Utilizando o exemplo dos links do  @Samuel, 404 pra mim seria "ei barista me veja um drink" e o barista não está no bar no momento, e 204 seria "ei barista me veja o drink X" e ele responde "infelizmente não tenho o X"

Comment: @ngueno Discordo do uso do *204*. Esse código significa que o servidor fez tudo certo, mas *não precisa* retornar um dado. Um bom exemplo disso é em requisições do tipo *DELETE*, que você não precisa retornar os dados deletados.

Comment: @ngueno considerando as diferentes respostas nos comentários eu diria que é uma pergunta pertinemte, e não acho "relativo e baseado na interpretação e definição de quem constrói a API", porque, apesar da pessoa poder criar uma API que deleta dados com o verbo GET, é semânticamente incorreto, assim como existe um status uma forma melhor de responder a requisição nesses cenários

Comment: @Guilherme, levo em consideração o [Modelo de Maturidade de Richardson](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html), a representação GET pode ser correta para o DELETE? Sim, ou não também! Se você modela sua API considerando o último nivel de maturidade está errado, se modela em outro nível a representação GET atende, é diferente fazer uma requisição DELETE para `users/1` e fazer um GET para `deleteUser/1`. Ambos estão corretos? Sim! Ambos atendem? Sim! Como disse é relativo

Comment: O retorno de um DELETE pode ser também 200 porque a entidade foi deletada, pode ser 204 por não haver retorno, cabe a interpretação de quem criou a API de documentar qual código está usando

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Primeiro, preciso dizer que uma das URLs parece estar mal construída.

Pelo texto entende-se que a URL `/users/name/guilherme` retornaria todos os usuários que possui `name` igual a `guilherme`. Se é uma busca, não é um recurso do servidor, então não pode ser mapeado para uma "uniform **resource** locator". Buscas são feitas por *query strings*, então a URL deveria ser algo como:

```
/users/?name=guilherme
```

Neste caso, o caminho que será acessado no servidor**¹**, definido pelo *path* da URL, será `/users`, portanto o recurso será devidamente localizado, será efetuada a busca e, neste caso, não serão encontrados resultados. Esta situação configura uma requisição tratada com sucesso pelo servidor, portanto uma resposta "200 OK"; como não foram encontrados resultados, provavelmente o corpo da resposta será uma lista vazia ou estrutura análoga:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "total": 0,
    "users": [],
    "query": {
        "name": "guilherme"
    }
}
```

Perceba que retornar uma lista vazia não significa responder com o corpo vazio. Isso dificilmente será recomendado. **Explícito é sempre melhor que implícito**. Por exemplo, na resposta acima não só foi retornado `"users": []` indicando a ausência de resultados como foi retornado `"total": 0` e a busca efetuada. Quem for tratar a resposta não terá dúvidas que a busca foi feita com sucesso e não obteve resultado. **Não ter dúvidas é sinal de ausência de ambiguidade e isso sempre é interessante**.

Já para a URL `/users/7` a situação muda. Você não está efetuando uma busca, mas sim acessando um recurso específico do servidor. Neste caso, não existindo um usuário com identificador igual a 7, o retorno deverá ser "404 Not Found".

Assim como comentado em [Pular a rota devido a parametro mal formatado é um erro de sintaxe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/357060/5878) a resposta 404 indicará que no momento da requisição o recurso não existe, mas no futuro, por ventura, poderá existir. Isso é importante para o cliente que está fazendo a requisição pois ele saberá que poderá futuramente fazer a mesma requisição e obter uma resposta diferente.

Mas perceba, isso não é uma regra, apenas algo que se aproxima ao idiomático do HTTP, pois busca eliminar ao máximo a redundância. Dependendo dos requisitos a redundância pode ser benéfica quando é de interesse praticar a [segurança por obscurantismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46057/5878)**²**. Em alguns casos gerar a redundância nas respostas HTTP é proposital para ocultar as regras de implementação da API, porém este é um contexto difícil de se trabalhar, pois aumentando a redundância você intrinsecamente aumenta o grau de dificuldade das integrações.

É comum, no entanto, vermos APIs com o retorno para `/users/?name=guilherme` sendo a resposta 404 da mesma forma:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "total": 0,
    "users": [],
    "query": {
        "name": "guilherme"
    }
}
```

E é comum também vermos a resposta com o corpo indicando os detalhes da resposta, o que diminuiria a redundância nesse exemplo. Se você reduz a redundância pelo corpo, o código da resposta passa a ser supérfluo, então dependerá diretamente das regras de implementação do seu projeto, só busque ser coerente. Ao definir a resposta em um desses recursos, utilize-a para todos os recursos semelhantes. Uma resposta 404 para `/users/?name=guilherme` e uma resposta 200 para `/posts/?category=sports` deixaria sua API incoerente e prejudicaria ainda mais qualquer integração.

## 204 No Content

A resposta 204 não deve ser usada para indicar que a busca não teve resultados. Semanticamente falando - e é isso que importa quando analisamos a fundo qual resposta utilizar - quando fazemos uma busca esperamos como resultado uma lista; quando a busca não possui resultados, será esperado que recebemos uma lista vazia. O servidor recebeu a requisição, a entendeu e conseguiu interpretá-la e executá-la. Retornar a resposta 204 neste caso implicará que o cliente assuma por inferência que não houveram resultados, mas nunca lhe dará a segurança disso.

Seria o mesmo que você chegar a um feirante, pedir se ele possui tomates para vender e ele não te responder. Você pode entender que por não ter te respondido ele não possua os tomates, mas também pode ser que ele não entendeu que foi uma pergunta e, portanto, julgou que não havia necessidade de uma resposta. **Gerar dúvidas no cliente não é semântico**. Diferentes clientes podem entender de forma distinta e a confusão estará armada. Você pode até documentar muito bem sua API e deixar explícito que haverá o retorno 204 quando não encontrar resultado, mas nesse caso você acaba gerando uma dependência muito grande com sua própria documentação sem qualquer tipo de benefício.

**Quando a resposta 204 No Content deve ser usada?**

Quando a resposta para a requisição não demandar um corpo. A situação mais comum disso é em atualizações de informações. Imagine a situação: o usuário acessou seu perfil no site, entrou em editar perfil e, assim, está vendo todas as informações atuais no formulário. Ele decide então alterar alguns campos e salvar. Nesse momento o usuário já possui todas as informações atualizadas na tela, por que você iria transmitir essas mesmas informações do servidor para o cliente sendo que você já as possui no cliente? Isso seria adicionar uma carga desnecessária na comunicação. Para o cliente em si isso talvez nem faça tanta diferença; o tempo gasto a mais para transmitir o corpo possivelmente seria de alguns milissegundos (ou segundos em casos piores)³, mas nada que chegasse a afetar a usabilidade da API. Porém, para um servidor que precisa responder milhares de requisições por hora, essa informação a menos que ele não precisará enviar pode fazer muita diferença.

Imagine que você precisa solicitar ao estagiário que ele mude a posição da cafeteira no escritório. Hoje ela fica na cozinha, mas você quer que ela seja instalada na sua mesa. Você pode chegar pro estagiário e pedir "Saudações terráqueo, por favor, mude a posição da cafeteira. Traga ela da cozinha para a minha mesa". O estagiário, eficiente como sempre, prontamente faz a mudança e a fim de te informar que a tarefa foi executada ele chega até você e responde uma das opções abaixo:

1. Pronto!
2. Pronto, mudei a cafeteira de lugar. Agora ela está instalada na sua mesa.

Concorda que ambas as respostas são completas e não deixam dúvidas do que foi feito? Mesmo que a resposta seja apenas "Pronto!", você já sabia que a cafeteira estava na cozinha e que seria instalada na sua mesa, então somente uma confirmação já seria suficiente. De forma análoga, a segunda resposta também te dá a confirmação que a tarefa foi realizada, com a diferença que ela também afirma aquilo que você já sabia.

Na resposta HTTP é a mesma coisa. Se você já possui conhecimento atual e você o modifica, você tem todas as ferramentas necessárias para inferir qual será o novo estado do recurso, assim apenas uma confirmação de sucesso bastará.

Inclusive, a resposta 204 No Content costuma possuir o cabeçalho ETag, que é um valor único responsável por identificar o estado do recurso. Assim, junto com as informações do recurso você possuirá a ETag atual do mesmo, que você deverá enviar junto com a requisição de atualização através do cabeçalho If-Match. Se o recurso no servidor estiver exatamente no mesmo estado que o cliente possuía, a atualização é autorizada e o novo ETag é devolvido na resposta. Caso o recurso esteja em um estado diferente do que o cliente possui, a atualização das informações deverá ser recusada informando ao cliente que a versão do recurso que ele possui está desatualizada. Isso evita o problema de "lost update".

- [Como evitar conflito de dados entre duas requisições PUT no HTTP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/319971/5878)

Vamos supor a situação: tenho as informações de um usuário (nome e e-mail) e desejo atualizá-las. Eu acesso o recurso:

```
>> GET /user/1 HTTP/1.1
>> Host: localhost
>> ...
```

Obtendo a resposta:

```
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< Content-Type: application/json
<< ETag: 1000001
<< ...
<<
<< {"name": "Anderson Carlos Woss", "email": "anderson@localhost"}
```

Eu altero o e-mail e mando salvar, fazendo, assim, a requisição de atualização:

```
>> PUT /user/1 HTTP/1.1
>> Host: localhost
>> Content-Type: application/json
>> If-Match: 1000001
>> ...
>>
>> {"email": "anderson@woss"}
```

Neste caso, eu tenho o nome e e-mail originais e sei o que foi mudado, então sei que o novo estado será `{"nome": "Anderson Carlos Woss", "email": "anderson@woss"}`, a resposta à requisição não precisa me dizer isso, seria redundante. Então uma possível resposta utilizando a HTTP 204 seria:

```
<< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
<< ETag: 1000002
<< ...
```

Veja que a resposta informará o novo valor de ETag indicando o novo identificador do recurso. Se for feita outra requisição de atualização informando o valor antigo, a atualização não ocorre e a resposta 412 Precondition Failed será retornada:

```
>> PUT /user/1 HTTP/1.1
>> Host: localhost
>> Content-Type: application/json
>> If-Match: 1000001
>> ...
>>
>> {"email": "john@due"}
```

A resposta seria:

```
<< HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed
<< Content-Type: application/json
<< ETag: 1000002
<< ...
<< 
<< {"error": "As informações estão desatualizadas. Atualize-as antes de fazer uma edição"}
```

Isso evitaria que a primeira alteração fosse sobrescrita pela segunda (problema de "lost update").

---

(1): Lembrando que a URL é [um valor opaco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232958/5878) e não necessariamente reflete a implementação do servidor, então dizer que o caminho acessado no servidor a partir do *path* da URL nem sempre é válido.

(2): Segurança por obscurantismo: [Como se chama a técnica de esconder componentes para assegurar informações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46057/5878)

(3): Desconsiderando casos especiais em que o corpo da resposta poderia ser gigantesco.

Comment: Uma verdadeira aula, muito bom.

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que o Status 404 (Not Found) seja mais adequado a recursos que de fato, não forem encontrados, mas esperava-se que fossem. Caso seja uma busca, do tipo pode ou não ser encontrado, eu usaria o 204, pois sinaliza que a busca não retornou resultados. Um array vazio: [] seria interessante, por ser autoexplicativo.

Answer (score 4):

Eu utilizaria 404 também, pois de acordo com a rfc rfc7231 que define os códigos HTTP este código diz respeito ao um recurso que foi procurado no servidor e não foi encontrado, então não se limita somente a url inválidas.

rfc:

```
 The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did
   not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
   willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Já o código 200 informa que a solicitação foi atendida com sucesso, ou seja, deve seu usado quando encontrou o recurso que estava sendo procurado.

rfc

```
The 200 (OK) status code indicates that the request has succeeded.
```

Fontes:
Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231

Comment: Como bem disse, o *status 200* informa que ocorreu tudo OK. E, por mais que não tenha trazido resultados, a requisição foi *OK*, ela funcionou como o esperado. Na [rfc7231](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), temos: *404 Not Found = The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI.*

Comment: Oi @ValdeirPsr, o link que você consultou acabou te induzindo ao erro, creio que o google provavelmente, este link que você colocou na verdade se refere a RFC2616, ela foi suspensa e substituída pelas RFCs (7230-7237), consulta o link https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html ai tem essa informação. Obrigado

Comment: Eu só utilizaria 404 se `name` fosse um identificador único, se for uma pesquisa deveria ser 200, pois tanto o endpoint quanto a pesquisa estão corretos, apenas não tem resultado.
Não acho semântico um retorno de erro para uma requisição que foi feita corretamente.

Answer (score -5):

Confesso que a ideia do **200 OK** me deixa com um pouco de duvidas, eu imagino a seguinte situação:

Você chega em uma loja pra pedir alguma coisa para o balconista, ai ele volta de mãos vazias e responde "Aqui está". esse seria o caso do *200 com body contendo 0 ocorrencias*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "total": 0,
    "users": [],
    "query": {
        "name": "guilherme"
    }
}
```

Eu acredito que ele deveria voltar ao balcão e te dizer "Desculpe, não encontrei oque você pediu", esse seria então o caso do *404 Not Found*.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

No caso do 404, colocar um body com 0 ocorrências me parece redundante, uma vez que algo que não foi encontrado não poderia ter um numero de resultados maior que 0

Comment: No seu exemplo o 404 está mais para "cheguei em uma loja e não encontrei um vendedor, então não consegui fazer meu pedido"